# How To Fix Padding Oracle (CVE-2016-2107) On Ubuntu/Apache/PHP

Tags: php, apache-2.4, openssl, vulnerability

I am trying to fix CVE-2016-2107.

I consulted several sites, which do not seem to provide a clear answer for all cases:

I use Apache2 2.4.12 with PHP 5.5.26.

I ran: `apt-get install openssl libssl-dev` and `sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0`.

It installed new OpenSSL but Apache/PHP still uses old installation, phpinfo() shows:

```
openssl
OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

Proof new OpenSSL is installed:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxxxx:/usr/bin$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
```

```
dpkg -l | grep ssl
ii  libflac8:amd64                           1.3.0-2ubuntu0.14.04.1               amd64        Free Lossless Audio Codec - runtime C library
ii  libgnutls-openssl27:amd64                2.12.23-12ubuntu2.2                  amd64        GNU TLS library - OpenSSL wrapper
ii  libio-socket-ssl-perl                    1.965-1ubuntu1                       all          Perl module implementing object oriented interface to SSL sockets
ii  libnet-smtp-ssl-perl                     1.01-3                               all          Perl module providing SSL support to Net::SMTP
ii  libnet-ssleay-perl                       1.58-1                               amd64        Perl module for Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)
ii  libssl-dev:amd64                         1.0.2h-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1       amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files
ii  libssl-doc                               1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15                   all          Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development documentation
ii  libssl1.0.0:amd64                        1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.19                   amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
ii  libssl1.0.2:amd64                        1.0.2h-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1       amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
ii  openssl                                  1.0.2h-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1       amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - cryptographic utility
ii  python-openssl                           0.13-2ubuntu6                        amd64        Python 2 wrapper around the OpenSSL library
ii  ssl-cert                                 1.0.33                               all          simple debconf wrapper for OpenSSL
```

```
apt-cache policy libssl1.0.2.
libssl1.0.2-dbg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0.2h-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
  Version table:
     1.0.2h-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

```
ubuntu@ip-xxxxx:/usr/bin$ apt-cache policy libssl-dev
libssl-dev:
  Installed: 1.0.2h-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
  Candidate: 1.0.2h-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.2h-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.19 0
        500 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.0.1f-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Can someone please help me tell Apache/PHP about the new OpenSSL installation? Thanks!

Comment: Late but [1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.19 contained this fix and others](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.19) well before this Q was asked.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you are using old PHP 5.5 which linked with old SSL libraries.
So current SSL libraries not used.
You can try to upgrade PHP packages too.

Comment: Cannot I not relink PHP to new SSL libraries?

Comment: It's hack but you can try to change symbol links to SSL shared libraries from old to a new ones.

Comment: Like libssl.so, libssl.so.1, libssl.so.1.0 and libcrypto.so, libcrypto.so.1.0, libcrypto.so.1.0.0 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu directory.

Comment: All in all, this does certainly not count as a "reasonable business IT practice". Reasonable would be to use supported versions of PHP and have all fixes installed.